# First load of a txt file using the sql command line

Tags: mysql, file, command-line, import

I work locally with WAMPSERVER2.5

I built my dadabase on OpenOfficeCalc: db.txt

```
- Character set: Unicode (UTF-8)
- Field separator: ,
- Text separator: "
```

I want to import "db.txt" in a table named "db_pma" which is in the database named "hct" (in PhpMyAdmin)

"db.txt" contains 2 fields:

```
- string_field (character string, max:30)
- numeric_field (sample: 5862314523685.256325632)
```

Questions:

1) Do I need to first create in PhpMyAdmin the structure of the table ("db_pma") which will contain the data?

2) I tried this code to import "db.txt"

```
  mysql -h localhost -u root
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'db.txt'
    INTO  TABLE dp_pma
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY 'AUTO';
```

It doesn't work.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` (for Windows) or `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` (for Linux) instead.